# Is there a way to remove specific characters from argument of a macro?

Tags: macros, characters, strings, makeindex, arguments

Suppose we have a macro saying,

```
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{m}{#1}
```

When it eats an argument, I want it to print whatever is in the argument **without** specific characters.

1. For instance, I want to remove all backslash in the argument. So

```
\foo{\mathbb{A}}
```

should give me `mathbb{A}` rather than a blackboard bold $\mathbb{A}$.

2. Another case: I want to remove all parentheses in the argument. So

```
\foo{(maybe) correct}
```

should give me plain `maybe correct` rather than `(maybe) correct`.

Any idea to achieve it?

**Update:** The following works at least for 2.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_str {(}%
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_str {)}%
    \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str%
}
```

**P.S.** I mean the above works for the example in case 2. However, as the comments point out, it does not work with macros. I expect a full solution to handle both cases: namely:

1. It can recognize macros and either drop the backslash of it or keep it (there should be an option)
2. It deletes certain characters, such as parentheses, from the argument.

Example 3:

```
$\foo[no macro,no parenthese]{(\mathbb{A})-correct}$
```

gives $mathbb{A}-correct$

Example 4:

```
$\foo[no parenthese]{(\mathbb{A})-correct}$
```

gives $\mathbb{A}-correct$

**A specific usage**: Phelype Oleinik asks for a specific usage, here is one:
I want to generate index entries automatically, so saying,

```
\myindex{(commutative) $\mathbb{R}$-ring}
```

should be expanded to either (with macros)

```
(commutative) $\mathbb{R}$-ring\index{commutative $\mathbb{R}$-ring}
```

or (without macros)

```
(commutative) $\mathbb{R}$-ring\index{commutative mathbb{R}-ring}
```

At this stage, I realize that another output is also meaningful:

```
(commutative) $\mathbb{R}$-ring\index{commutative R-ring}
```

So, please leave your ideas.

**Another Update:** I think the tricky part of this question is how to deal with the special tokens such as backslash and braces. Another there is something like \c_backslash_str, but they are not in the correct catcode and Moreover, the order of expanding is complicated.

Comment: there is not a backslash in the argument `\mathbb` is a single token, you could apply `\string`  or `\detokenize` to make a string

Comment: Use expl3 and str_remove_all etc.. Tokenization is a thing though, and note that "give" is a bit vague in that the command itself is not expandable but it does "print" on paper when executed

Comment: @user202729 not sure how to use str_remove_all to do this. What the argument gives is merely a list of tokens rather than a string.

Comment: Then I guess you can convert it to a string first, something like that.

Comment: 2 will not work with `\foo{(\mbox{maybe}) correct}`.

Comment: ... and `\tl_remove_all:Nn` will not work with `\foo{\mbox{(maybe)} correct}`. This smells like an [xy problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/134574).  What is your actual use-case?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik When I talk about case 2, I assume there is no backslash to separate the situation. A full solution should solve both 1 and 2.

Comment: With all the corner cases you'd have to worry about, it seems like it'd be much easier to have `\myindex[arg to index]{what to show}`, and if the optional argument isn't present then `\index{what to show}`.